# Async angular drop down performance suggestions

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I’m having a huge list of 20K names, calling a service to get these names in async manner and loading it in drop down. Below is the code snippet, which is working. However, this slows down the dropdown and hangs the page for a few seconds.
Is there any better way to try this?  Any pointers would be useful to call the service dynamically with first few characters typed.

Exploring angular/uxc first time.

```
<div *ngIf="{hugeList : listService.nameList| async} as name">
<div *ngIf="name.hugeList">

<uxc-select-dropdown
  label="Name"
  attribute="name"
  displayField="name"
  valueField="name"
  contenteditable="true"
  [selectionData]="name.hugeList"
  id="Emp.name"
>
</uxc-select-dropdown>
```

Comment: use autocomplete in this case and normally the user will no scroll the hole list ,there is no other way ‍♂️

Comment: great ! Thanks. I have used typeahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use autocomplete in this case and normally the user will no scroll the hole list of the data and the data is very big for the browser to render .

you can use angular material component [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) or another option is the [autocomplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) component from primeng library or any other components or library he idea here is when your type a request will go to get some of the data base on search value so you will get few data can the user choose from and you can set the limit like 500 record at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You should not send all data (20k) at the same time from the server. The server needs to support queryparameters as search,page,currentpage and give back these datas( ex: in responseHeaders) including totalAmountOfPages. You can use this in a standard search(like google)with paging or a dropdown with autocomplete in the client.

Comment:  Jens , you answer is  correct in case we want to display the data like grid or data table with pagination support ,up for this  , but the question was about suggestions to the user

Comment: Thanks for the response. Mayby I'm misunderstanding the case, but I use the same type of server resources for autocomplete. I just don't use the paging headers then. The server only returns about 30 results as you type in the autocomplete. But I add latency on typing in milliseconds to reduce the amount of server calls.  I just don't want to get the complete data from the server. No point in returning more records than can fit on the screen height

Comment: this one is a nice implementation 